# How to upload a collection from random binary file?

Tags: java, random, binaryfiles

I'm writing a project in Java and want to define the class Test with main () with 2 collections: a HashSet  and a LinkedList  of
at least 10 items.
They must be loaded from the binary files, respectively cards.dat and date.dat Such files they must be produced previously in a random manner.
How can I handle this request?

Comment: What is in the files? what have you tried so far? You'll need to open the file (https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-read-file-java-string-array-list) and parse the data.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/ - write a program to generate random collections and serialize them into files. then just read in your main project

Comment: In cards.dat there are the cards (seed and value), in date.dat there are the date(day, month, year). I have not tried anything because I do not know how to create binary files randomly

Comment: This website is for helping you solve a specific problem you are facing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you want to get good help here.

Comment: @ShadowKill97 Please add a few lines of what you can find in both `cards.dat` and `date.dat`